# iwlwifi 7265d-25.u and -26.u missing (kali linux)(firmware)

Tags: kali-linux, firmware

I see this error message every time i boot to my kali-linux. May someone know how to fix this i can not find `iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode` and `iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode`.

```
root@kalidaz:~# dmesg | grep iwlwifi | head -5  
[   12.241960] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode (-2)  
[   12.241963] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2  
[   12.241984] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode (-2)      
[   12.241986] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2  
[   12.568391] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode    
root@kalidaz:~#
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

All you can do is ignore those messages as iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode and iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode were never released to the linux-firmware git site.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/

The iwlmvm module handles the firmware upload and will look for the highest version supported by the kernel, if not found it will write an error message to the log and look for the next lower number and continue the cycle until it finds firmware or arrives at the lowest version supported